# Getting SFINAE correct with functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I've written a quick thing which determines whether a given type (and arguments) is convertible to a plain function pointer.  It works like this:

```
template <typename F, typename...Args>                                                                                                                        
struct is_stateless : std::is_convertible<F, typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type (*) (Args...)>::type                                                    
{};
```

This works well most of the time, but it has one serious drawback: the use of `std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type`.  If you've accidentally supplied the wrong arguments for your function (say you left off a `&`) you'll get template errors due to `result_of` not having a `type` field. I'd much prefer my `is_stateless` struct to just be "false" in this case (as it would be if you supplied a "correct" functor and arguments which didn't happen to be convertible to a function pointer).

I'm open to using C++11 and c++1y features present in GCC4.8.* and below.  Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Hm, I wonder if checking the type of `std::decay` (or using a similar technique to what it does) could actually help here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz not sure that would work - arbitrary classes with a () operator and an FP conversion operator should be allowed to pass this. std::decay won't capture that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating `result_of<F(Args...)>` where `Args` is not correct for `F` is not allowed. If you do it anyway, there is no way to recover from an error.

What you can do is avoid using `result_of`: you can achieve the same result with `decltype(declval<F>()(declval<Args>()...))`. This should work SFINAE contexts too:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename F, typename...Args>
void funcptr_helper(...);

template <typename F, typename...Args>
auto funcptr_helper(F, Args...) -> decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...));

template <typename F, typename...Args>
struct funcptr {
  typedef decltype(funcptr_helper<F, Args...>(std::declval<F>(), std::declval<Args>()...)) (*type)(Args...);
};

template <typename F, typename...Args>
struct is_stateless : std::is_convertible<F, typename funcptr<F, Args...>::type>::type {};

int main() {
  auto f1 = [](int i){ return i; };
  static_assert(is_stateless<decltype(f1), int>::value, "");

  int j = 0;
  auto f2 = [=](int i){ return i + j; };
  static_assert(!is_stateless<decltype(f2), int>::value, "");

  static_assert(is_stateless<std::vector<int>& (*) (std::vector<int>&, int, char, bool), std::vector<int>&, int, char, bool>::value, "");
  static_assert(!is_stateless<std::vector<int>& (*) (std::vector<int>&, int, char, bool)>::value, "");
  static_assert(!is_stateless<std::vector<int>& (*) (std::vector<int>&, int, char, bool), const std::vector<int>&, int, char, bool>::value, "");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work: `static_assert(is_stateless<std::vector<int>& (*) (std::vector<int>&, int, char, bool), std::vector<int>&, int, char, bool>::value, "oh dear");` returns false, for example.  I'm still not sure what the error is though - any thoughts? @hvd

Comment: `auto funcptr_helper(F, Args&&...)`

Comment: @MatthewMilano The general idea does work, I was just missing `&&` in the signature of `funcptr_helper`, causing the intended overload of `funcptr_helper` to be rejected.

Comment: @MatthewMilano Actually, on second thought, avoiding deduction is probably easier here. Edited.